Cloud run FastAPI container shuts down and won't restart
In my GCP logs:
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [1]

Which is fine, serverless computing, that's expected.
Except when I make fresh requests, they get 504'd (perhaps 503?) whichever one means timeout; I'd expect a new instance to spin up and respond?
Weird thing is: it worked fine for months; not sure what I could've changed that would make this happen.
No errors in the logs, no warnings, nothing. Just a shutdown and then no startup.
Edit: to respond to a comment, the container is definitely running because it'll answer requests for a few hours before dying.
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.12

WORKDIR /backend/
COPY requirements.txt /backend/requirements.txt
RUN pip install \
    --no-cache-dir \
    --upgrade \
    -r requirements.txt

COPY resources/ /backend/resources/
COPY source/ /backend/source/

WORKDIR /backend/source/
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]

# main.py

import fastapi

import endpoints


app = fastapi.FastAPI()


for router in endpoints.routers:
    app.include_router(router)


Check your startup and liveliness checks, the new instance might not be running.

Nope, definitely running and serving 100% of traffic; I'll edit the post to reflect that
